# SaltStack doesn't start docker container

Tags: docker, salt-stack

Started *salt-minion -l debug* and getting the following output:

```
[DEBUG   ] Docker-io running:{'status': True, 'comment': 'Container <container_name> was started', 'id': '<container_name>', 'out': None}
[DEBUG   ] Docker-io running:False
[ERROR   ] Container '<container_name>' cannot be started
```

It would be really nice to get some more info why the container cannot be started. Does anyone know how?

Looking at the [salt dockerio code](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/states/dockerio.py#L1265), it seems the *'out'* parameter is empty.

```
salt-minion --version
salt-minion 2015.5.8 (Lithium)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the error in:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>-json.log
```